# Oracle Listener stopped working

Tags: oracle

I have an issue with my Oracle listener. I am running on RHEL6 and all of a sudden Listener stopped working. I am able to `sqlplus / as syadmin` and it works fine from terminal.

Whenever I run command `lsnrctl status`, `lsnrctl start`, `lsnrctl stop` it gives below error.

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dev32018)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12538: TNS:no such protocol adapter
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00508: No such protocol adapter..
```

I can ping dev32018 and it is successful. And in the log file below message is shown.

```
 type=UNKNOWN level=16 host_id=dev32018
 host_addr=10.68.11.186
 TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect
 TNS-01153: Failed to process string: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dev32018)(PORT=1521)))
```

Everything was working fine and no modifications was made on `listener.ora` or any configuration file,  the issue happened all of a sudden, we restarted the machine , restarted the network and  still no use.
Anybody who can help in resolving issue.?

I have an issue with my Oracle listener. I am running on RHEL6 and all of a sudden Listener stopped working. I am able to `sqlplus / as syadmin` and it works fine from terminal.

Whenever I run command `lsnrctl status`, `lsnrctl start`, `lsnrctl stop` it gives below error.

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dev32018)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12538: TNS:no such protocol adapter
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00508: No such protocol adapter..
```

I can ping dev32018 and it is successful. And in the log file below message is shown.

```
 type=UNKNOWN level=16 host_id=dev32018
 host_addr=10.68.11.186
 TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect
 TNS-01153: Failed to process string: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dev32018)(PORT=1521)))
```

Everything was working fine and no modifications was made on `listener.ora` or any configuration file,  the issue happened all of a sudden, we restarted the machine , restarted the network and  still no use.
Anybody who can help in resolving issue.?

Updated as requested in comments

```
 tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /app1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
 Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEV32018 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dev32018)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = dev32018.corp.ae)
    )
  )

DEV3DB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dev32018)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = dev32018.corp.ae)
    )
  )
```

**Listener.ora**

```
 listener.ora Network Configuration File: /app1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
 Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dev32018)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

LISTENER2 =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dev32018)(PORT = 1522))
    )
  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /app1/oracle

---------------------------------nslookup 10.68.11.186------------
oracle@dev32018 admin]$ nslookup 10.68.11.186
Server:         10.51.156.161
Address:        10.51.156.161#53

** server can't find 186.11.68.10.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN

--------------------------------nslookup dev32018---------------------------

[root@dev32018 etc]# nslookup dev32018
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.51.156.161, trying next server
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.55.155.32, trying next server
Server:         10.37.164.207
Address:        10.37.164.207#53

** server can't find dev32018: SERVFAIL

-------Telnet
[root@dev32018 etc]# telnet dev32018 1521
Trying 10.68.11.186...
telnet: connect to address 10.68.11.186: Connection refused
```

Comment: show files `tnsnames.ora` `listener.ora`.  run `nslookup dev32018`  and `nslookup  10.68.11.186`  and  `telnet dev32018 1521`

Comment: @DmitryDemin: Updated post with requested details

Comment: show file `/etc/hosts`

Comment: try to change hostname to IP address in `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora`.  change `(HOST = dev32018)`  to `(HOST = 10.68.11.186)`

Comment: It did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by running the script "relink " in oracle home/bin directory 
$ORACLE_HOME/bin
relink all

It took some 30 seconds to complete and afer that the listener command started working.
I am not sure what was the problem and what this script has corrected.
Thank you for all

Answer (score 0):

Make you sure that you are running `lsnrctl status` in Oracle user if not.

Please try in terminal or log as Oracle USER.

`$ su
 # su - oracle
 $ whoami`

In this point `whoami` should give you back **Oracle** and you can run `lsnrctl status`

And the listener will be start now :D

You can do a `sh` file and add this to `etc/init.d` to autorun that when you start again the machine.

### Update

You will need to run the next comand in Oracle user.

`. /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh`

This is for Oracle XE, you can find this specific comand in the documentation of installation of you Oracle Version. And next you will be able to run `lsnrctl status`

Comment: I didint try this but I solved the problem by running relink  script in the same directory